# PHP rtf lite обрезает кириллицу

Tags: php, rtf

Использую библиотеку [PHPRtfLite](https://github.com/phprtflite/PHPRtfLite) для создания rtf файла. Пример кода:

```
$rtf = new PHPRtfLite();
$section = $rtf->addSection();

$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRows(2);
$table->addColumnsList(array(4,4,3,3,3));

$cell = $table->getCell(1, 1);
$cell->setTextAlignment(PHPRtfLite_Table_Cell::TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
$cell->writeText('Фамилия Имя Отчество');
...
```

Но в документе это и остальные поля выводятся обрезанными, то бишь вместо `"Фамилия Имя Отчество"` выводится `"Фамилия Им"` Помогите плз, уже весь инет перерыл, как исправить проблему? Файл сохранен в UTF-8 кодировке.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду файл скрипта? У меня ваш код прекрасно отработал: http://prntscr.com/bibclu, http://prntscr.com/bibcr6. Попробуйте другие варианты вывода, не используйте таблицу, попробуйте сэмплы, которые идут в комплекте с библиотекой. Библиотека требует `iconv` для работы, проверьте, активировано ли расширение у вас.

Comment: @GinoPane да, файл скрипта сохранен в UTF-8. iconv работает, проверил. В сэмплах есть пример, называется utf8.php Там вроде как русский текст отображается, но там его крайне мало. У меня тот же самый текст в таблице тоже шикарно отобразился. Видимо, это библиотека косячит((

Comment: Так добавьте больше текста в сэмпл и посмотрите, что получится. 
У меня при увеличении количества просто растягивается ячейка: http://prntscr.com/bibhzx. Я использую PHP 7.0.1, хотя вряд ли это имеет значение, так как должно все работать начиная с версии 5, согласно документации. Вы исключили вариант, что это просмотрщик, который вы используете, обрезает текст при просмотре файла?

Comment: Вы правы, все дело оказалось в редакторе. Libre office подвел. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было не только в редакторе. Исправил так в php.ini:

```
mbstring.func_overload = 0
```